# How is this loop's time complexity O(n^2)?

Tags: c, for-loop, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

How is this loop's time complexity O(n^2)?

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i -= c)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j <=n; j += c)
        {
            // some O(1) expressions
        }
    }
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Change `// some O(1) expressions` into `static int cnt; printf("%d %d %d %d\n", ++cnt, n, i, j);`. run the code with `n = 4` and later `n = 8`, to see why.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption**

```
n > 0
c > 0
```

**First loop**

The first loop start with `i=n` and at each step, it substracts `c` from `i`. On one hand, if `c` is big, then the first loop will be iterated only a few times. (Try with `n=50`, `c=20`, you will see). On the other hand, if `c` is small (let say `c=1`), then it will iterate `n` times.

**Second loop**

The second loop is the same reasoning. If `c` is big, then it will be iterated only a few times, if `c` is small, many times and at the worst case `n` times.

**Combined / Big O**

Big O notation gives you the `upper bound` for `time complexity` of an algorithm. In your case, first and second loop upper bound combined, it gives you a `O(n*n)=O(n^2)`.